# How to boot Windows from a USB Drive?

Tags: windows, usb, boot

I want to install Windows Os from a USB drive. How can I make my USB Drive bootable, so that I can format my PC with a USB Drive.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu bootable USB stick:

- Goto http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download
- In *Step 2* Select "I would like to create a: **USB stick**" option
- Click on **Show me how**

For Windows7 bootable USB stick:

- Refer http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2009/12/-the-usb-flash-drive.ars